# How to set pattern for date/time converter in a theme?

Tags: xpages

I am trying to set a date/time converter using a theme but I can not get it to work.

I have tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
<control>
    <name>InputField.EditBox</name>
    <property mode="override">
        <name>converter</name>
        <complex type="xp_convertDateTime">
            <property>
                <name>pattern</name>
                <value>DD-MM</value>
            </property>
        </complex>
    </property>
</control>
```

If at all possible, how do I set a pattern for date/time converters in a theme?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is timing. The theme settings are only applied during the render response phase.

The examples that work for complex properties are setting browser-related settings, like dojoAttributes. So the values are applied as the HTML is passed to the browser.

Converters work during the ProcessValidation phase (I've seen that with PhaseListeners). So the converter needs to be there much earlier in the lifecycle.

If I'm right, you won't be able to use a theme to apply a converter. You'd probably need to extend the Edit Box control and create your own component.